# Scheme: list all bindings in scope

Tags: r7rs, chibi-scheme

In R7RS or chibi-scheme, is there a function I can call to get a list of symbols containing all bindings in the current scope?

As a comparison, in Python, I can use functions [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) and [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) to see what names are available in the current scope.

I'm learning scheme and I think it would be pretty useful for exploring the language if a feature like that were available.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such procedures are defined in R7RS. For Chibi, Environment object contains all bindings of the environment, however, it can't be accessed from Scheme world.

If you are using REPL on Chibi, you may want to check the `(chibi repl)`: http://synthcode.com/scheme/chibi/lib/chibi/repl.html